# Change folder in python3 script using a bash command

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I trying to change the path where I located in a `python3` script using a bash command. 
I use this small code but it doesn't work:

```
import subprocess

args = ['cd', '/foo/bar/xxx']
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

I also try to use `subprocess.call()` and `subprocess.run()` but it doesn't change the path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing running those commands, you are launching a new process, which changes its directory to `/foo/bar/xxx`, then exits.  To affect the path of the parent program, use [os.chdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=chdir#os.chdir) like so:

```
import os
os.chdir('/foo/bar/xxx')
```

Fun fact: this is why bash and other shells have `cd` as a builtin; any program equivalent to cd could only affect its own path.